# How to fix selecting today's date, deducting a few days from the date and adding the date to an EditText

Tags: java, android

I want when a user taps on the Duedate EditText they get a date selector dialog with the default date set to today. The date they select will be subtracted 280 days and the resulting date will be set into another EditText called Lastperiod. The problem is when the user taps the EditText for the first time, it works just fine. But if they try re-selecting the Date again, the Duedate and the LastPeriod text view do not change. One has to tap the EditText for the changes to appear. Worse still the date that appears keeps deducting itself. Please help me find my logical error such that even when the user wants to reselect the date the calendar does not have to restart from 280 days back.

I have tried to be resetting the date to today as the first thing when the EditText is clicked but it still does not work.

```
Duedate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.due_date);
     LastPeriod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_period);

    Duedate.setOnClickListener(this);
    LastPeriod.setOnClickListener(this);


    date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, 
int dayOfMonth) {

            view.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   }
```

**Function to Deduct 280 Days from the Selected Date.**

```
   public void Deduct_Date(){
    myCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE,-280);
    String myFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( myFormat);
    LastPeriod.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

}
```

**Function to Reset date to today's date.**

```
public void ResestDatetoToday() {

    date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            view.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);


        }
    };
}
```

**Implementation of On click Listener**

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.due_date:
            new DatePickerDialog(DateActivity.this,date,myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            ResestDatetoToday();
            String myFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( myFormat);
            Duedate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
            //LastPeriod.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
            Deduct_Date();
            break;
    }
```

I excepted when the user taps the clicks the DueDate edit text, they are able to select a date with the default date being today. that works fine. But when the user wants to select another date other than today's date, it does not reflect on the Edit texts unless they tap again which will produce a date that is 280 days back. It does not start from today.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>From what I understand from your code, you are using the same variable **date** for both the listeners. So the variable is getting set to a new listener and thus misbehaving.</strike>

**Try the below mentioned approach:**

**Step 1:** Create a Class named **DateTimeUtility**

```
    public class DateTimeUtility {

            public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";

            public static void showDatePicker(Context context, DateTimeListener dateTimeListener, long dateTime) {
                if (context == null || dateTimeListener == null) return;
                Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (dateTime > 0)
                    myCalendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);

                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        dateTimeListener.onDateTime(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
                    }
                };

                new DatePickerDialog(context, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
         public interface DateTimeListener {
              void onDateSelected(long dateTime);
          }

public static String getFormattedDateTime(Long time, String format) {
        if (time == null) {
            return String.valueOf(0);
        }
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            return dateFormat.format(time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return String.valueOf(0);
        }
    }
        }
```

**Step 2:** Use the class from your activity/fragment. Inside your Fragment/Activity:

```
    private long selectedDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Duedate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.due_date);
        LastPeriod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_period);

        Duedate.setOnClickListener(this);
        LastPeriod.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.due_date:
                DateTimeUtility.showDatePicker(mContext, new DateTimeUtility.DateTimeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSelected(long dateTime) {
                            DueDate.setText(DateTimeUtility.getFormattedDateTime(dateTime, DateTimeUtility.DATE_FORMAT));
                            selectedDate = dateTime;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(selectedDate);
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -280);
                        LastPeriod.setText((DateTimeUtility.getFormattedDateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), DateTimeUtility.DATE_FORMAT)));
                        }
                    }, selectedDate);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: It still does not change anything.